# How do I make an object reactive in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming

Let's say I have an object

```
var object = {
name: "Example",
value: 1
}
```

I want to put it in a session

```
Session.set("Display", object);
```

and have an handlebars template show it on the page.

Then, if I do

```
object.value += 1
```

I want the page to instantly display `2` without the need to call Session.set("Display", object); again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `Session.set` after. If you want to avoid that you have to make your own reactive objects (which will at their core do the same thing that `Session.set` does).

If you still want to go about it this way there is a package on the atmosphere repository called [reactive-extra](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/reactive-extra) which can help you make your own reactive objects:

```
var obj = new ReactiveObject({name: "Example",value: 1});
obj.value +=1;
```

Comment: There are functions called Meteor.render() and Deps.autorun() that use a reactive data source and run when their dependancies change. There is no way I can use them to do so?

Comment: With all of them you still require a way to tell Meteor the dependencies have changed (like Session or Deps.depends). It then tells Deps.autorun/Meteor.render to run again with the new values.